# a little tricky mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 tables on a mysql db

```
auctions:

seller: seller id
transaction_date: unix timestamp


comments:

seller: seller id
rating (-1, 0, 1)
comment_date: unix timestamp
```

so, I want to calculate the seller rating of the seller, which is the sum of the ratings, right before the transaction. and I want to know how many comments the seller have right before the transaction.

I want to obtain two more columns like this:

auctions:

seller, transaction, **seller_rating, num_of_comments**

any ideas?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following could work. Basically, you build a table that lists all relevant comments with each transaction, and then perform the counting from there:

```
SELECT auctions.seller, auctions.transaction_date, SUM(comments.rating) AS seller_rating, COUNT(comments.comment_date) AS num_of_comments
  FROM auctions
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comments 
    ON auctions.seller = comments.seller
  WHERE auctions.transaction_date > comments.comment_date
GROUP BY auctions.seller, auctions.transaction_date
```

Comment: `SUM(comments.rating) AS seller_rating, COUNT(comments.comment_date) AS num_of_comments`

Comment: I guess that's fair. I also forgot the `GROUP BY`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
  a.seller,
  a.transaction_date,
  SUM(c.rating),
  COUNT(*)
FROM auctions a 
LEFT JOIN comments c on c.seller = a.seller AND c.comment_date <= a.transaction_date
GROUP BY a.seller
```